# Why is the QByteArray read from a file smaller than the newly downloaded QByteArray?

Tags: c++, qt, qfile, qbytearray

I am attempting to compare a `QByteArray` of an already saved html file with a `QByteArray` that was just downloaded. I have to convert the `QString` of the file's contents to `QByteArray` in order to compare them (or vice versa) and comparing bytes seems like the cleanest method, however when converted from `QString` to `QByteArray`, the size of the new QByteArray is smaller than what it should be. `QByteArray QString::toLocal8Bit() const` states that if it is undefined, the characters will be suppressed or replaced. It also said that it uses `toLatin1()` by default and tried to use ASCII since that is what a website is encoded in. I still get the same results.

```
bool NewsBulletin::compareDownload(QByteArray new_contents, QString filename)
{
    bool return_what = false;
    qDebug() << "I am in compareDownload";
//    qDebug() << new_contents[1];
//    qDebug() << new_contents[1] << endl
//             << new_contents[2];
    QFile file(application_path + filename);
    if (file.exists())
    {
//        QString new_contents_qstr(new_contents);
        file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
        QTextStream in(&file);
        QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("ASCII"));
        QString file_contents = in.readAll();
        QByteArray file_byte_array = file_contents.toLocal8Bit();
        qDebug() << "outputting new file array";
        qDebug() << new_contents[5] << new_contents.size();
        qDebug() << "outputting old file array";
        qDebug() << file_byte_array[5] << file_byte_array.size();
        for (int i=0; i<=file_byte_array.size(); i++)
        {
            if (file_byte_array[i] != new_contents[i])
            {
                return_what = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (i == file_byte_array.size())
            {
                qDebug() << "compareDownload will return false, duplicate file.";
                return_what = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "compareDownload will return true, DNE.";
        return_what = true;
    }
    return return_what;
}
```

The output of the `qDebug()` from the function is:

```
I am in compareDownload
outputting new file array
T 64704
outputting old file array
T 64576
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the api for hours, I found the reason for the bytes being different.

```
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
```

`QIODevice::Text` needs to be removed. This flag changes end of line terminators into the terminator for cpp, "\n", thus giving a byte difference.